# Php and MySQL for a recipe database

Tags: php, mysqli

I’m building a food recipe website databases. Have a few problems inserting on to 2 tables with one function. I’m building in with baby steps to get it right little by little. I have got it to work one time but it is when I add more code it stops.

Getting a SQL syntax error when I add ingredient 2 to my html. It worked with one input box.

```
function insert_recipe($recipe){
    global $db; 

    $sql = "INSERT INTO Recipe ";
    $sql .= "(name, description) ";
    $sql .= "VALUES (";
    $sql .= "'" . $recipe['name'] . "',";
    $sql .= "'" . $recipe['description'] . "'";
    $sql .= "); ";
    $sql .= "INSERT INTO Ingredient ";
    $sql .= "(name) ";
    $sql .= "VALUES (";
    $sql .= "'" . $recipe['ingredient1'] . "'";
    $sql .= ");";   
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    // For INSERT statements, $result is true/false
    if ($result){
        return true;
    } else {
        //INSERT failed
        echo mysqli_error($db);
        db_disconnect($db);
        exit;   
    }
}
```

There is a measurement table I don’t have a picture of that I’m not working on that part yet. I’m thinking it may have something to do with each and input box for ingredients has the same name `<input name="ingredient" type="text" class="form-control trowlgray" placeholder="Suger" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1">`going to need to be able to have an ID for every ingredient.

Comment: What are you trying to ask? no one is going to read that story.... please write short and precise answer. Also use PHP PDO ...

Comment: @Umair PDO vs mysqli doesn't really matter here, both allow prepared statements, etc.

Comment: I’m hope this explains my question without having it too long. I’ve been working on this project for five years. Getting better as I work on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that `mysqli_query()` only support single statements, not multiples.

The good news is that I *know* that [`mysqli_multi_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) supports multiple statements separated by a semi-colon in a single call.

Comment: Will mysqli_multi_query() add every ingredient with its own ID?

Comment: @AlanBell It will do whatever your sql queries tell it to do.

Comment: Ok that worked but now I have to find a way to add more ingredients. Can you just point me in the right direction I’ll see if I can figure it out.

Comment: @AlanBell that would be a whole new question.  but looking at what you already have, you need to tie the recipe together with its ingredients somehow.  When doing a CRUD type app (create retrieve update delete), I work on the R first, then C and U and finally D.  Knowing how you will use and access the data helps you determine how you store it....